# R - brazilmaps (borda dos estados)

Tags: r, ggplot2, mapas

Criei um mapa dos estados de SP e MG utilizando `brazilmaps()`.

Neste mapa eu preenchi algumas cidades com valores.

Entretanto, gostaria de fazer com que a borda dos estados aparecessem no plot.

Como faço isso?

Segue o que estou tentando.

```r
library(brazilmaps)
library(maptools)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(tidyverse)

    # Definindo paleta de cores ----
    createColors  <- colorRampPalette(c("yellow","red","darkgreen"))

    # Definindo cidades e estados ----
    cidades_sp_mg <- get_brmap(geo = "City", geo.filter = list(State = c(31,35))
                               ,class = "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")

    estados_sp_mg <- get_brmap(geo = "State", geo.filter = list(State = c(31,35))
                               ,class = "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")


    # Criando Mapa ----
    load(file="dados/data.Rdata")

    # Agrupa por municipio, conta quantas coop. cada municipio tem
    dScore_data <- data %>% group_by(cod_municipio_ibge) %>% count()


    # Gera mapa das cidades
    mapa_data <- plot_brmap(cidades_sp_mg, 
                                       data_to_join = dScore_data, 
                                       join_by = c("City" = "cod_municipio_ibge"),
                                       var = "n"
                                       )


    mapa2_data <- plot_brmap(estados_sp_mg, 
                                       data_to_join = dScore_data, 
                                       join_by = c("State" ="cod_uf"),
                                       var = "n"
    )


    MinhasCores_data  <- createColors(4)

    png("dados/Cities.png", width = 800, height = 600) 

    print(mapa_data) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=MinhasCores_data,name="Qtd.", na.value = "lightgray") + 
      labs(title="Cities",caption = "Font") + 
      theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"),title = element_text(face="bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20),
            plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 10)) 
+ plot(mapa2_data)

    dev.off()
```

Com o `+ plot(mapa2_data)` dá erro. Mas sem este comando, os estados são gerados e as cidades preenchidas normalmente, sem as bordas dos estados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi o problema da seguinte maneira:

```r
library(geobr)

# Definindo bordas de SP e MG     
mapa_SP <- read_state(code_state="SP", year=2018)
mapa_MG <- read_state(code_state="MG", year=2018)
```

Depois disso, adicionei esses arquivos ao plot do mapa com o `geom_sf()`

```r
print(mapa_data) +
      scale_fill_gradientn(colours=MinhasCores_data,name="Qtd.", na.value = "lightgray") + 
      labs(title="Cities",caption = "Font") + 
      theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"),title = element_text(face="bold"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size=20),
            plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0.5,size = 10)) +
  geom_sf(data=mapa_SP, fill="transparent", color="black", size=0.8, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_sf(data=mapa_MG, fill="transparent", color="black", size=0.8, show.legend = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma opção viável é usar o pacote ggplot2 e a função geom_polygon para fazer a leitura dos dados, adotando "color" tal como no exemplo abaixo. É possível alterar a cor e a espessura ao seu gosto.

```
ggplot(mapa_data) + 
  geom_polygon(..., 
               color = "white", size = 0.1)
```